# Intellij - Remove bars on left side of code?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, editor

This is a really hard thing to search for because anytime I say "lines" or "bars" in searches, I get things completely different from what I'm trying to solve for. Here's my problem though:

[image: Bar Example]

The bars that go from one bracket all the way down, how do I remove them? Thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To switch it off temporarily, Right click on the left panel and de-select "Show Indent Guides".

[image]

Also, as pointed out by  Bohuslav Burghardt in comments, to permanently disable it, uncheck Show vertical indent guides in Settings/Editor/General/Appearance.

Or, press double shift and type "show indent guides" and switch it off.

Comment: It's worth noting that this disables the guides only temporarily for the current file. If you want to disable them permanently, uncheck _Show vertical indent guides_ in _Settings/Editor/General/Appearance_.